# Realistic use case for cursors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I read both the Microsoft Docs and [this article](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/sql-server-basics-of-cursors). I however can't seem to find where I could only use cursors and not something else so I'd appreciate If someone could give a few examples.

I also came across this [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222868/what-is-exact-use-of-cursor-in-sql-server) and Jeffrey Hantin gave me more doubts.

Comment: As Jeffery says in your linked answer, besides administrative operations where you want to do something like execute dynamic sql based on each row in a set of data, they should just be avoided.  If all you are doing is querying data, I have yet to find a situation where a `cursor` was necessary or performed better than a set based solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is exact use of cursor in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222868/what-is-exact-use-of-cursor-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine a command which **must get a literal parameter** like BCP.

Try to read 100 XML files living somewhere on your disc and you have their path and filenames in a table.

In this case you will **create the statements dynamically** and use `EXEC` to run each separately.

This might be any kind of loop, but a `CURSOR` seems to be the closest.

The general answer is: **Avoid loops**, most needs can be solved without using a loop. With SQL one should use *set-based* approaches over *procedural* approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I find I only ever use cursors for administration tasks. For example I have a script that runs through my high activity large tables. That rebuilds the indexes overnight that query itself is pretty set based. However I have multiple customer databases on the same box with the same structure. I would wrap the maintenance script in a cursor that pulls out the database names and loops through them.

I find this reduces the amount of work I have to do, as the list of databases to work through is generated by the cursor. If I add customers/ delete customers the maintenance is unaffected. If I run up a new box I can add that as part of the set up process so when I get round to setting up a customer system on the new box it is automatically being maintained.

Here is a sample of somebody using the same concept to backup all of their databases. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/

Same benefits that I've mentioned in that it is defined once and whether you add remove or move databases they are already automatically in the backup plan