# Why does Loop Procedure in MYSQL return error?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, mariadb, procedure

I´m relatively new to SQL and just playing around with some codes. The idea is that this procedure should loop through TABLE movies and SET value for each row in COLUMN summary to NULL however it returns error :

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@MaxValue INT;
DECLARE @Counter INT;
SET @MaxValue = SELECT MAX(id) FROM ...' at line 4*

Can you please advise what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ReplaceSummary()

BEGIN 
    DECLARE @MaxValue INT;
    DECLARE @Counter INT;
    SET @MaxValue = SELECT MAX(id) FROM movies;
    SET @Counter = 1;
    WHILE @Counter <= @MaxValue DO
        UPDATE movies SET summary = NULL WHERE id = @Counter;
        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: 1) User-defined variables (which name starts with `@`) does not need in declaration and cannot be declared. 2) Setting SELECT output to a variable via SET operator needs the whole SELECT to be wrapped with the parenthesis.

Comment: The procedure performs the operation which may be performed by simple `UPDATE movies SET summary = NULL;`...

Comment: @Akina - thanks a million! I made the changes and now it works nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE movies SET summary = NULL
```

Comment: yeye, I know that this can be done very easily via simple query, I just wanted to understand how looping works in SQL...

Comment: Search for cursor or use this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222868/what-is-the-use-of-a-cursor-in-sql-server/12721794